# Has anyone used proguard to obfuscation of .war file and succeed?

Tags: proguard

Has anyone used proguard to obfuscation of .war file and succeed? if yes then please tell me the exact steps to obfuscation of war.
I am not finding any ideal document on web for my requirement.
I have created my web application in spring boot and jsp.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <proguardVersion>5.3.3</proguardVersion>
                    <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
                    <outjar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</outjar>
                    <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                    <options>
                        <option>-dontshrink</option>
                        <option>-dontoptimize</option>

                        <option>-adaptclassstrings</option>

                        <option>-keepattributes
                            Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
                            SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod</option>

                        <option>-keepnames interface **</option>

                        <option>-keepparameternames</option>

                        <option>-keep class
                            !com.slm.proguard.example.spring.boot.domain.**
                            { *; }</option>

                        <option>-keep class com.slm.proguard.example.spring.boot.service {
                            *; }</option>

                        <option>-keep interface * extends * { *; }</option>

                        <option>-keepclassmembers class * {
                            @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired *;
                            @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value *;
                            }
                        </option>
                    </options>
                    <libs>
                        Include main JAVA library required.
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                        Include crypto JAVA library if necessary.
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
                    </libs>
                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                        <version>5.3.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Yes. What's your exact question? I use a maven plugin                      <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId><artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I want to obfuscate .war file of web application using proguard

Comment: @SimonMartinelli edited the question 
added plugin  for proguard used in pom.xml

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: Till now i have created a .war file using above mentioned configuration in pom.xml file.
Now in Input/output option of proguard how to add path of folder contains the .class files.
If I'm trying to do that using .war file, It's not allows me to reach to folder contains .class files.
I'm referring this document: http://bratonfire.blogspot.com/2012/01/war-file-obfuscation-using-proguard.html

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with a JAR created by proguard, it seemed ok but tomcat didn't find anything inside. After a long search I found that unzipping and re-zipping with an ant-task the exact same file make a working one.

Here is the added configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>fixzip</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <!-- ******************** ********* ******************** -->
                    <!-- ******************** IMPORTANT ******************** -->
                    <!-- ******************** ********* ******************** -->
                    <!-- It may seems strange to unzip and re-jar the file -->
                    <!-- but the JAR made by Proguard is somehow not readable -->
                    <!-- by Tomcat and Spring beans aren't recognized -->
                    <!-- *************************************************** -->
                    <!-- Fixing JAR. -->
                    <move file="target/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar"
                        tofile="target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}_proguard_base.jar" />
                    <jar destfile="target/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar">
                        <zipfileset
                            src="target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}_proguard_base.jar"
                            includes="**/*.*" />
                    </jar>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```